# JavaScript array to Django form input dropdown list

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, django

```
<script>
    let myArr = ["ProductA","ProductB","ProductC"];
</script>
```

I want to make a Django input dropdown using this javascript array.

```
<input type="text" name="product1" value="0" maxlength="500" class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_product1">
```

When user will click on this Django form input, I want a drop-down list to appear, from which users can select an option.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? What is the issue here?

Comment: I have a javascript array, using that array, I want to create a dropdown list of array items on a Django text input field so that the user can select a specific item from that dropdown list. Can u help me do that please?